# Fatal error 'Invalid Document' after entering development mode and updating plugins in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

Was just updating some modules in my M2 2.3.3 site and have ended up with a fatal error in the front end and backend.

The site was in production mode so I put it in maintenance and then into development mode. When updating the modules the command hung. Refreshing the site returned:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document Element 'arguments', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The type definition 'array', specified by xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the type definition of the element declaration. Line: 10 in /home/.../vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:168 Stack trace: #0 /home/.../vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(132): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) #1 /home/.../generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('graphql') #2 /home/.../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(206): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy->read('graphql') #3 /home/...dev.saf in /home/.../vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php on line 168
```

Running any command via CLI returns

```
Invalid Document
Element 'arguments', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The type definition 'array', specified by xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the typedefinition of the element declaration.
Line: 10
```

Would anyone happen to know what has happened here?

Cheers